# pytube v. 9.5.0 signature error in mixins.py

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

I am wondering if anyone is experiencing the following error in v 9.5 of Pytube, mixins.py:
 signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['s'])

What steps were taken to fix this bug if encountered?

```
if js is not None:
        signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['s'])
    else:
        # signature not present in url (line 33), need js to descramble
        # TypeError caught in __main__
        raise TypeError('JS is None')
```

line 49, in apply_signature signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['s'])
KeyError: 's'

Answer (score 0):

In `mixins.py` (which is the PyTube file that is throwing the error) try replacing line 41:

```
if 'signature=' in url:
```

with:

```
if ('signature=' in url) or ('&sig=' in url) or ('&lsig=' in url):
```

Apparently from time to time YouTube changes the way the signature is presented in the URL.

[Link](https://github.com/minwook-shin/pytube/commit/f7ed32da09b6387713b15c7eb3ff5f17516e7ea2)